# PHP Yii Relations: Movies & cinemas & showtimes

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I working on movies & cinemas showtimes guide.

and I have showtime table (photo #1) and I have times table (photo #2)

and I need to show list of cinemas with showtimes in movie page like this

Cinema name: Time1 - time2 - time3

Grand Cinema:** 00:18 - 00:20 - 00:22 .... ets

**My code it's not work.. and what can I write to show this in view file**

> Error: The relation "cinemas" in active record class "movie" is not
>   specified correctly: the join table "{{showtime}}" given in the
>   foreign key cannot be found in the database.

**Movie model has relation:**

```
'cinemas' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Cinema', '{{showtime}}(movie_id, cinema_id)')
```

**Cinema model has relation:**

```
'times' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Time', '{{showtime}}(cinema_id, time_id)')
```

**Cinema model should have named scope:**

```
public function times_by_movie($movie_id) {
    return $this->with(
        array(
            'times'=>array(
                'condition'=>'`movie_id` = :movie_id',
                'params' => array(':movie_id'=>$movie_id),
                'joinType' => 'INNER JOIN'
            )
        )
    );
}
```

**MoviesController > actionView**

```
public function actionView($id) {
    $movie = Movie::model()->with(
        array(
            'cinemas'=>array(
                'scopes'=>array(
                    'times_by_movie'=>$id
                )
            )
        )
    )->findByPk($id);
    if (!$movie)
      throw new CHttpException(404, 'Movie not found.');

}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: First of all you have to decide if you have Showtimes model or showtime. That's pretty much different models in your application. Secondly try to stick to the same naming style, so your code is a bit more readable. Third, please, read carefully Relational Active Record tutorial: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr

Comment: I read it but i need solution.. help me plz

Answer (score 1):

So you have models `Movie`, `Showtime`, `Time`.
Your `Movie` model has relation:

```php
'cinemas' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Cinema', '{{showtime}}(movie_id, cinema_id)')
```

Your `Cinema` model has relation:

```php
'times' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Time', '{{showtime}}(cinema_id, time_id)')
```

Also your `Cinema` model should have named scope:

```php
public function times_by_movie($movie_id) {
    return $this->with(
        array(
            'times'=>array(
                'condition'=>'`movie_id` = :movie_id',
                'params' => array(':movie_id'=>$movie_id),
                'joinType' => 'INNER JOIN'
            )
        )
    );
}
```

In `MoviesController`->`actionView` you should have:

```php
public function actionView($id) {
    $movie = Movie::model()->with(
        array(
            'cinemas'=>array(
                'scopes'=>array(
                    'times_by_movie'=>$id
                )
            )
        )
    )->findByPk($id);
    if (!$movie)
      throw new CHttpException(404, 'Movie not found.');

}
```

Something like this. Should be tested though.

Comment: also I have this error = >
The relation "cinemas" in active record class "movie" is not specified correctly: the join table "{{showtime}}" given in the foreign key cannot be found in the database.

Answer (score 1):

you have to make an assosiation table for MANY_MANY ralationship